# mv: prompt to rename or overwrite

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rename

```
find /home/csuser/testfiles . -type f -name "*.c" -exec mv '{}' /home/csuser/src/ \;
```

The above command will simply overwrite files which have the same name. How can I make `mv` prompt me to either overwrite the existing file or replace it, for each file name which already exists at the target?

Comment: Bad idea. Usually you'll be breaking things when altering a directory tree structure. `cp -r /home/csuser/{testfiles,src}; find /home/csuser/src/ -type f -not -name "*.c" -delete` would keep all original *.c files along with the directory structure

Comment: Can you give this question a proper title and move the existing title into the main thread.

Comment: Add -i to the mv command

Answer (score 4):

The manpage of the `mv` command (`man mv`) shows the following entry:

```
       -i, --interactive
              prompt before overwrite
```

So, using `mv -i ...` prompts before overwriting.

Comment: This merely allows you to cancel the copy if you don't want to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple shell script wrapper to prompt you for each existing file.

```sh
find /home/csuser/testfiles . -type f -name "*.c" -exec sh -c '
    for file; do
        dest=$0/${file##*/}
        if [ -e "$dest" ]; then
            ls -ld "$dest" "$file"
            read -p "Enter new name for the second, or just ENTER to overwrite the first: " newname
            if [ "$newname" != "" ]; then
                dest=$0/${newname##*/}
            fi
        fi
        mv "$file" "$dest"
    done' /home/csuser/src/ {} +
```

We obscurely but conveniently pass in the destination directory as `$0`.

Comment: 2nd 'do' error, i change it to 'then' ,it works but then it shows error at the ' done' ' line with { } + . Also i dont understand the " -exec sh -c ' " and the difference with my "-exec mv '{}' " .Thanks a lot for your time bro.

Comment: Pleae don't call me "bro". You are right that that should be `then`, not `do`. The simple `exec mv` obviously does not invoke the `read -p` etc

Comment: The last `fi` was also in the wrong place; sorry about that.

Comment: If your `find` is really old, it might not support `-exec ... {} +`. You can switch to `-exec ... {} \;` but this is somewhat less efficient and elegant.

Comment: Alright i have done everything as you said. the previous errors have been solved. now i see that i have a destination problem as it doesnt shows any destination. i replaced $0 as you said with my path like this : `dest=/home/csuser/Desktop/src/${file##*/} `but no results. what am i doing wrong? Moreover the fi you said that you put wrong what is the correct place?

Comment: I have already edited the code to correct it. You would replace `/home/csuser/src/` after the final closing quote with `/home/csuser/Desktop/src/` if that's the destination you want to move files to. (The first argument after the closing quote gets copied into the `$0` of the subshell which runs `sh -c '...'`)